# MySQL check if key value exist more then n times with different date

Tags: mysql

How I can check if a value occur in my table 2 or more times, but it must be on two diffferent dates.
I don't need to know how much times it occur, I only must know if the passed key occur two or more times.

As the table holds many records, I'm looking for a way that in best case not all reccords must be scanned.

```
id | key | request_datetime
1  | 111 | 05-05-2017
2  | 222 | 06-05-2017
3  | 111 | 06-05-2017
4  | 111 | 06-05-2017
5  | 222 | 06-05-2017
```

If I check for the key 111 i should get a indicator that is true, if I check for 222 i should not get any back or a indicator for false.

So far I have tried to group by key and request_datetime then count the rows, the performance was too bad this way.

Comment: try group by the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question literally translates to a query which aggregates the keys and counts the number of distinct request dates for each key.  In the query below I retain only keys having the same request date appearing 3 or more times, but you can change the threshold to whatever you want.

```
SELECT
    `key`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY `key`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT request_datetime) > 2   -- or whatever value you want
```

Note that I had to place the column name `key` into backticks as it is a MySQL reserved keyword.  You should avoid naming your tables and columns with keywords unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [having](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) something like this:

```
SELECT key, COUNT(DISTINCT request_datetime) AS request_count
FROM myTable
GROUP BY key
HAVING request_count > 1;
```